# Error when downloading an email attachment with python

Tags: python, imap

The error I get says:

> - IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/nithinpathak/Documents/Automate/attachments/Payment Advice Note from 06/28/2018.PDF'. I understand that the error is because python is not able to detect the file. But not sure which part of the code is wrong

Im using the below code to download attachment

```
import imaplib, email, os

map_url = 'imap.gmail.com'
attachment_dir='Users/nithinpathak/Documents/Automate'
con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
con.login(user, password)
con.select('INBOX')

result, data = con.fetch(b'11', '(RFC822)')
raw = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
get_attachments(raw)

def get_attachments(msg):
  for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype()=='multipart':
        continue
    if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
        continue
    fileName = part.get_filename()

    if bool(fileName):
        filePath = os.path.join(attachment_dir, 'attachments', fileName)
        if not os.path.isfile(filePath):
            print fileName
            fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
            fp.wirte(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, slashes in a path name are always interpreted as a directory delimiter even if it is in Windows, which uses backslashes as a directory delimiter. The file name `Payment Advice Note from 06/28/2018.PDF` is therefore interpreted as a file 2018.PDF under the sub-directory of `Payment Advice Note from 06/28`. You should simply rename it to something without the slashes.

Comment: I have removed backslashes from the attachment, but it has still go the IO error. Is it because of attachment_dir path since I am using mac

Comment: You also should not use relative path name. Try using `/Users/nithinpathak/Documents/Automate` instead as your `attachment_dir`.

Comment: thanks..It worked..is there any reason for not to use relative path?

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, relative path is relative to the current working directory, which is usually not the root directory that you want, but the directory where the application (i.e. Python) is installed. Always use absolute path when opening files unless you use `os.chdir` to change working directory to one you want beforehand.